# Align to Object misbehaving

Tags: modeling

Whenever I go to align two objects (in Object Mode) I expect their origins to snap to the target. S, X, 0 should do this. It is currently doing something else; making all vertices go to the target origin as well (regards if median, active etc.), as if I had done this in Edit Mode.

Toggling Manipulate Centre Points will stop this transformation happening, but attempting to rotate with R will stop functioning until I toggle back. The Transformation Panel will let me enter rotational values but it's not the same as having it on your mouse.

This error has only existed for me since today and I've done all I can to track down an answer elsewhere. It's affecting all work files including the startup file.

The funny thing is, this seems to be permeating through space and time. I have not only purged the directory, upgraded from 2.78 to 2.79, changed the install directory to a different disk, and loaded factory defaults for every test, this issue still plagues me. A friend I sent my work file to says he sees the same thing but is localised to that file, while it's a bit more intense for me, to say the least.

Any magical shortcut I need to hit or hidden .ini file I need to nuke to restore normal functionality and fix my workflow would be appreciated.

[image: And it was going so well too]

Comment: I don't understand your issue... S,X,0 should scale your object to be flat on X axe... as it is in your screenshot. I am not aware of using scaling (S) to snap objects...Can you attach your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: Here you go.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5013" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5013/)

and I don't know what to tell you other than S, X/Y/Z, 0 has been the primary means of aligning the various parts in this work file, the previous iterations of said file and other previous projects. While I'm in edit mode it behaves as expected so most of the actual workflow isn't affected, but for years now I've used that command to align things and they have never deformed like that before.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why it should align (if you dont have Manipulate Center Points turned on) when you use Scale. I find it perfectly logical that after Scale along X to 0 objects become flat :-/